# Web alerts unrecognized logins

Tags: web

Is it possible to identify if the login is being made from a strange machine? Creating a list of machines recognized by login?

I have tried methods to capture data from the browser through .js, thus generating a fingerPrint but without success, because it is not possible to identify the machine if it is in a network for example.

Here's an example where Google or Microsoft do this, I logged into my account on a computer that I had never used, so I get the notification and I can administer the machines that are recognized for my login.

Is it possible to implement this without installing plug ins on the user's machine? through only my WEB application?

**Examples:**

[image: 1 - Alert]

[image: 2 - Managment]

Comment: Thats not a question to be solved in c#, but in the browser. Have you tried googling this topic? You're not the first one to solve this question...

Answer (score 0):

you want to do something called fingerprinting.  This is client side code

basically you are uniquely identifying the user, with all the possible information in which you believe is unique.

This could be a concatenation: 
 - using cookies
 - ip address
 - browser agent (which has os, and browser, and some plugins)
 - java version (if installed)
 - flash version (if installed)
 - screen resolution
 - all misc versions of information you can grab via javascript

take a look at

https://github.com/jackspirou/clientjs

https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways to achieve this.

1. If your clients are having static IPs then probably you can maintain a list of IPS (Kind of whitelist). Any other request can be treated as unintended request and you can write a logic to generate an alert. This is cumbersome method since static IP may be changed over a period of time.
2. If you have limited no of users, then probably you can generate a certificate and install it on clients machine. Other users who is not having the certificate can be treated as unintended users. They can't access your application since they don't have your certificate. This method is feasible only if your application is intended only for some small no of users since you need to install the certificate on your clients machine.